Eclipse not refreshing CSS and HTML files correctly
I've been working on a Java servlet project recently (running on Tomcat server), and for reasons I can't figure out, whenever I make changes to my HTML/CSS files, as I launch the project, I see no changes whatsoever on my browser. Refreshing the project, restarting Eclipse, even restarting my laptop won't fix the issue. I can also tell it's not a cache issue since opening it on different browsers shows the exact same web page. Usually I can see the changes by the next day.
Build automatically is enabled for anyone wondering. Also, I don't know how relevant this is, but usually I use VS Code to edit those HTML and CSS files (not a big fan of Eclipse in general, but University gotta University, so at least I try to use it only as a build tool and not as a text editor); although even changes made directly through Eclipse won't work

You are launching the project from Eclipse, not from Maven or another CLI, right? Where are these files in the project? When you change them outside of Eclipse, are you Refreshing the project so it knows those files have changed? Does Cleaning or explicitly Cleaning the Tomcat Work Directory from its context menu in the Servers View make a difference?

@nitind I've been launching it from Eclipse, yes, and the files are stored under src/main/webapp (with the css files having their dedicated folder under that directory). I've just tried cleaning both and nothing changed

Is your project on an actual local drive? Are you letting the project build?

And what do you mean, "cleaning both"?

@nitind with "cleaning both" I mean I clicked on both "clean" and "clean work directory" on my Tomcat installation (and nothing changed). Also yes, the project is on my local drive. Although, what do you mean by "letting the project build"? Technically nothing's stopping it from doing so, since "build automatically" is enabled

That would be everything that should be a part of it. Is any other build/deployment system involved?

@nitind nothing, all I'm doing is launching the project on Tomcat through Eclipse itself

Anything special about this Tomcat runtime, its location or version, or how much free space there is? Deployments are staged in your workspace's .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core directory as a folder with a name starting with "tmp". Something must be happening where the updated contents aren't written there ever, somehow.

@nitind so my version is 9.0, installed in a dedicated folder inside C:/program files, and I have plenty of free space. Also, that "tmp" folder you mentioned is called "tmp0", for some reason, could it be a naming issue that's interfering?

No, I said it would be a 'name starting with "tmp"', so tmp0 is normal. That your Tomcat installation directory might not be writeable could be an issue. Have you tried letting the IDE download a Tomcat 9 runtime for you, unpacking it into a folder your user owns, and seeing if it makes a difference?

@nitind tried that, Eclipse didn't let me pick a folder to download and install a new Tomcat installation. I tried installing it manually in a desktop folder, but that didn't solve the issue either

When you say, "installing it manually", is that something other than unzipping it?

@nitind I've used the .exe installer, forgot to mention that

I'm not sure if it would make a difference, nor why, but perhaps try using the zip file version. It involves the fewest variables.
